# HR schema in Ubuntu

Tags: sql, oracle, ubuntu-14.04

I have installed sqldeveloper 12c. I have NOT installed sql plus or oracle xe of any kind. How can I get access to HR schema in UBUNTU system?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need a DB of some sort.  I would use the Vbox appliance or second choice docker images.

Here's a bblog that goes over the choices: http://tuhrig.de/3-ways-of-installing-oracle-xe-11g-on-ubuntu/

Download Links for reference:

- Free Option : XE since it's free , as you mentioned, http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/database-technologies/express-edition/overview/index.html
- OTN based License options:

  - VBox Appliance: 
    https://medium.com/oracledevs/i-installed-oracle-sql-developer-now-what-71230b9c9303
  - Database OTN Downloads:
    http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/enterprise-edition/downloads/index.html
  - Docker scripts for DB EE 
    https://github.com/oracle/docker-images/tree/master/OracleDatabase

Comment: Yes Kris. Though the steps to install XE is humongous in Ubuntu I successfully installed Oracle XE. Now I am able to connect it using sql developer. Thanks for your help